# Differences between the three Xbox 360 Wireless Receiver drivers

Tags: drivers, xbox360, game-controller

There are three different versions of Xbox 360 Wireless Receiver drivers installed with Win10:

1. Xbox 360 Wireless Receiver for Windows [15/02/2007]
2. Xbox 360 Wireless Receiver for Windows Version: 10.0.17763.1 [14/09/2018]
3. Xbox 360 Wireless Receiver for Windows Version: 2.1.0.1349
   [13/08/2009]

I purchased a such receiver long time ago and one of the steps of installing this device is to choose a driver from the list:

[image]

As far as I remember, I should select the 2009 version driver. I'm wondering what the differences are between these drivers. Why shouldn't I selected the 2018 version? Aren't all such receivers all similar in terms of communication protocol, form factor, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm wondering what the differences are between these drivers.

There isn't a difference except for the OS the driver was released for.  The drivers from 2007 and 2009 are Windows 8.x drivers.

> Why shouldn't I select the 2018 version?

That is the only driver you should select.

> Aren't all such receivers all similar in terms of communication protocol, form factor, etc.?

This depends if you actually got a genuine Microsoft XBOX 360 wireless receiver.  The only reason you should select the Windows 10 driver is for compatability reasons.